# My ionic 3 project is much different from what i see in tutorials

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, project

I am new to ionic and i have been watching a lot of tutorials. In these tutorials i see them using angular and controllers and scopes. But in my project i cant find a place to make the app module and controllers. When i open my pages all i see are typescript and html files. Where do i make use of angular in the project ie make the controllers and scope

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ionic 3(or 2), which uses Angular2+. That's why you don't see the scope and such things, because in Angular2+ they got rid of all of that.

Comment: So how do i do all the things the scope does. like giving a model etc

Comment: Thank you very much. As i switched to 3 it worked like charm